# Hot Meta Post To Deleted Question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, community-bulletin

It seems that the "Hot Meta Posts" has lured me in, built my hopes up with an interesting question and then left me high and dry. It seems to show questions even after they were deleted.

After clicking on "[Should I flag a user who tries to vandalize his own question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261888/should-i-flag-a-user-who-tries-to-vandalize-his-own-question?cb=1)", I land on the "This question was removed from Meta Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation" page. Refreshing the page several times and even clearing cache makes no difference.

Might I suggest that a deleted meta question not show up in the "Hot Meta Posts" box?

Comment: Just get 10k+ rep and you can see deleted posts.  :)

Comment: Searching for similar questions from the 404 lead to this one.  The system works.

Comment: Presumably deleted questions are already filtered, it was just cached.  I wouldn't expect the host meta posts to be queried on demand.

Comment: It was deleted 15 minutes ago.  Not everything updates within a second.

Comment: @Servy No, but I would think the system would be able to rebuild the cached list when it recognizes a deleted question?

Comment: @Tom The whole point of caching is to avoid doing those types of checks on every single page load.  It'll go away in a few minutes, and having a link like that there for just a few minutes simply isn't the end of the world.

Comment: I'm not talking about every single page load. I'm talking about the Delete button. When the question is deleted, which happens once, the list (in my mind) should have been updated / recached.

Comment: Was just about to come here to post the same thing :)]

Comment: @Tom, but that still would put a significant load every time the delete button is hit, to check to see if the deleted Q is a hot Q or not.

Comment: @Joe I haven't seen how Stack Overflow code looks, but I would think when the Hot Meta Posts gets built that it would add a flag to the question and the question could make that determination there. Then the check wouldn't be invasive at all, since the question has to be loaded anyways. But again, I don't know the back-end code for Stack Overflow. Seems like a pretty simple thing that would improve user experience if it's done properly.

Comment: Add a flag where?  You're still taking sql queries all over the place.  You have to put a flag in a table, and that table would have to be queried every page load and/or every delete press.  Instead they just build the hot meta whatever as a static web page, include it in each page load, and re-create the page every so often, one query executed per fifteen minutes or whatever instead of many many queries, one per delete.

Comment: @Joe Is each individual question cached? I would imagine that each time the question loads, it loads the most recent information for the question. So if `Question.IsHotQuestion == true`, rebuild cache. On Rebuild Cache, Set the 4 "hot" questions `IsHotQuestion` to `false`, and when the next 4 are picked, set the questions `IsHotQuestion` to `true`. That leads to the same amount of load for individual questions and then an addition of 8 queries for the rebuilding of the Hot Meta section. Or if you group those queries, 1 query.

Comment: I doubt IsHotQuestion is an attribute of Question.  It's probably simply a table of question IDs.  Honestly, the SO people are pretty bright.  Isn't it worth giving them some credit for being halfway competent?  If it worked as you suggest it seems like it wouldn't make sense to have this problem...

Comment: @Joe, thats why it's a feature request, because we are having this problem. Also, since it has recently changed, perhaps its something minor they missed. Doesn't matter how bright you are, small things can still be missed. Regardless, this is simply a request to improve something that is less than ideal.

Comment: It happened again, to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265900/what-happened-to-your-common-sense?cb=1 - this is pretty silly. I can't imagine it would be so difficult to check whether a question is a hot question when you delete it, and remove it from that list (and recache) if it is? Looking up the hot questions list might happen a jillion times a day, but I can't imagine deleting posts from meta happens nearly so often.

Comment: Its been 45 minutes and *its still on the list*. In fact, it must be getting cached server side because it was there on my first page access (and already deleted). Even if its not *that* big a deal, I can understand lower rep users being very frustrated by this.

Comment: I'd call this a bug rather than a feature request.

Comment: This bug is still open. It happens to me right now on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327981/an-user-offering-bounty-ignores-my-answer-for-2-days-accepts-a-silly-answer-of?cb=1 .

Comment: Yep, I've got the same @anderas, was about to post about it until I spotted this question. It's annoying me as well, as the title uses incorrect wording and I want to correct it :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several years later, in August 2020, this was [implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353493/377214): if a question on Hot Meta Posts is deleted, it will be immediately removed from the bulletin.